# Can't debug async function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, pdb

`pdb.set_trace()` seems not to work in async function in certain condition. Did anyone meet before?

The code snippet

```
@app.middleware('http')                                                         
async def http(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        request.state.db = SessionLocal()

        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        response = await call_next(request)
        request.state.db.commit()
    except:
        request.state.db.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        request.state.db.close()
    return response
```

The trace segment

```
-> response = await call_next(request)
(Pdb) 
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60426 - "GET /api/test HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 389, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 179, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 25, in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, self.call_next)
  File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/TopLinker/code/backend/app/middleware.py", line 32, in http
response = await call_next(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/bdb.py", line 113, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

- Python3.8

Comment: Please add a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Tim I can't reproduce it. I have tried a simple demo of async which uses pdb, and it's work well. The raising error at code happens in a sophisiticated project. I just wanna ask if someone encountered before.

Comment: A smaller example works as expected, but a larger project it does not? I suppose you have to start looking at what is different than about the smaller example and the larger and start from there.

Comment: "in certain condition" What are these conditions? There are all sorts of non-async reasons why tracing does not work for async code (e.g. compiled code), listing all would not be focused enough for [so]. Can you clarify *in what way* tracing "does not work"? Does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
As per the docs , It should work . Have you tried this.. or need a line number for error?

Comment: The [asyncio debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode) has a specific and limited effect. This does not include tracing.